# Between versus within person effects in longitudinal data

Tags: panel-data, multilevel-analysis, stata

I'm conducting a daily diary data analysis (10 days of dairy on various constructs of interest), where I'm interested in using previous day's variable X to predict the following day's Y.

I created a grand mean centered version of the predictor X to indicate between person effect, and a group mean centered version of the predictor X to indicate within-person effects. When I entered both X between and within in the same model to predict the outcome, neither was significant. However, when I entered between-person (X between) and within-person (X within) effects within in separate models, both predictors were significantly associated with Y.

I'm trying to understand what this mean? Why is this? Should I choose one version of X for the final model? If so, should I choose uncentered X, grand mean centered X, or group mean centered X? Is the model with both grand mean centered and group mean centered X correct?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't use Stata, but there should be a function to estimate a multilevel model in an integrated manner from the original data. You seem to try to do this manually by re-centering the X in different ways, but this is not how it should be done.

Comment: A significant result means that there is evidence that a variable has a nonzero coefficient *given all other variables in the model*. Your two different versions of X may be strongly correlated and may carry about the same information about Y, so that each comes out insignificant if the other one is still in the model, even though there is significant information in X overall.